# what does the error means in CruiseControl?

Tags: java, ant, cruisecontrol

I was configuring the Continuous Integration Environment of a Java project, the tools i use are CruiseControl, svn and ant.

first, i installed the latest JDK--JDK 1.7

second, i check the project code to the projects folder, then i start the CC, i got an error whick says cannot find the third party jars. in eclipse, you can import the third party jars into the project easily, but in CC, there is no such kind of IDE, so i modified the Ant script of the project----build.xml, to configure the path.

at last, i rebuild the project in CC again, and i got an Error:
Warning: [options] have not set the guide class path with -source 1.6 
C:\cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.4\projects\myproject\src\main\java\net\controller\myproject\manager\Manager.java:181: Error: -source 1.6 do not support using String in switch:
switch (columnName.toString()) {

what dose the Waring means?

Comment: The error implies that you are trying to compile a Java 1.7 source code with a Java 1.6 JDK as java 1.6 doesn't support using `String`s in `switch()` statements.

Comment: but my JDK version is 1.7. i find a properity in the build.xml:<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.6"/>
but this properity is not used in other place in the build.xml,what does this properity mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hava solved it, just modified the following sentences:

```
<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.6"/>
<property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.6"/>
```

to

```
<property name="ant.build.javac.source" value="1.7"/>
<property name="ant.build.javac.target" value="1.7"/>
```